# Why doesn't re-assignment to __builtins__.dict affect creation of new dictionary objects?

Tags: python-3.x, built-in

A classmate asked a question about overwriting the built-in class *dict*, and after some poking around I became even more uncertain.

Take the built-in dict. I can assign this variable:

```
>>> dict=5
>>> dict
5
```

Now I've lost access to dict (would this be shadowing like in C++ or is it different?) but I still have access to the class via **builtins**.dict. But I can overwrite that as well:

```
>>> __builtins__.dict = 6
>>> __builtins__.dict
6
```

But even doing this doesn't break the class itself:

```
>>> stillDict = {'key': 'value'}
>>> stillDict
{'key': 'value'}
```

So why does the class still "work" after I've shadowed it? How does the interpreter know I'm making a dictionary with this assignment, and how is the dictionary constructed since it obviously doesn't actually require `__builtins__.dict`?

**edit**
Taking this a bit further, from simeon's answer which says it's because I'm creating a dictionary literal ...

before overwriting, I can do this:

```
>>> a = dict()
>>> a.items
<built-in method items of dict object at 0x0000000002C97C08>
```

after overwriting dict and `__builtins__.dict`, I can do this:

```
>>> b = {}
>>> b.items
<built-in method items of dict object at 0x000000000288FC88>
```

Which leads to a follow-on ... 
Both of these are still "dict objects", is the dict class just using a constructor to make a dict object? Why do I still have access to the built-in methods once I've shadowed the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{'key': 'value'}` is a dictionary literal so that continues to have the behaviour of producing a dictionary. Python doesn't need to look up what `dict` means - it skips this step and directly generates byte code to construct a dictionary:

```
>>> def f(): {'a': 3}
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 BUILD_MAP                1
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('a')
              9 STORE_MAP
             10 POP_TOP
             11 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

In the byte code it continues to use `BUILD_MAP` as before (i.e., it builds a map / dictionary based on the code you've written).

The meaning of `dict` has changed as you mentioned.

---

Regarding the follow-up question: you haven't shadowed the dictionary class / type - you've only changed the meaning of what `dict` means. You cannot take the dictionary type away and Python produces it when using a dictionary literal (e.g., `{}`).

Once you have an object of type `dict` you have access to its methods (like `items()`) - it's just that you've constructed it using syntax (which you can't influence) rather than a call to `dict()` (which you can influence).

Comment: @DanielB.: Your edit changed nothing. `dict` still exists in the Python internals, it's just not accessible _by name_. Any non-name based approach to accessing and using a `dict` continues to work.

Comment: @DanielB. I have expanded the answer regarding that.

Comment: Hm. So even '__builtins__.dict' is just a handle, not the actual class?

Comment: @DanielB. that's true, it's only a name which can be redefined.